# Email $_FILES['name'] as list

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, each

After a user has completed uploading multiple files I display the files uploaded on screen. I'm also trying to include that same list in the body of an email. Absolutely everything works, including displaying each file on screen, except the $message_body only lists the last file name in the array. Any ideas??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['ship-it']) AND $_POST['ship-it'] === "yes") {
    $yesupload = $_POST['ship-it'];
    preg_match("/yes/", "".$yesupload."");

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['tray']['name']); $i++) {
         $filename = $_FILES['tray']['name'][$i];
         $s_name = $_FILES['tray']['tmp_name'][$i];
         move_uploaded_file($s_name, 'https://example.com/inbox/'.$filename.'');
    }
    $info = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $message_body = "".$_POST["email"]." uploaded the file: ".$_FILES['tray']['name']."
    https://example.com/inbox/".rawurlencode($filename)."

    User Agent: ".$_POST["id"]." ".$info."";

    $mail_options = [
        'sender' => 'sender@gmail.com',
        'to' => 'receiver@gmail.com',
        'subject' => 'new file sent',
        'textBody' => $message_body
    ];

    try {
        $message = new Message($mail_options);
        $message->send();
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        echo 'error: ';
    }
    echo "<p>All done. Here's what you sent:</p>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['tray']['name']); $i++)
    {
        echo "<ul style='list-style-type:square'>
            <li>{$_FILES['tray']['name'][$i]}</li>
            </ul>";
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>Files to upload: </p> <br>
   <input type="hidden" name="ship-it" value="yes">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>">   
   <input type="email" name="email" required="" autofocus placeholder="Your email address"><br><br>
   <input type="file" multiple name="tray[]"  required="">
   <input  type="submit" value="Upload"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are looping over `$_FILES['tray']['name']` when you show your message on the screen but you don't do that when you build your message body.

Comment: 1. seems _https://url can't be there in `move_uploaded_file`. 2. the call of `preg_match` is not clear there.

Comment: ^^^ Exactly ^^^ Use a server path and not a URL.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I stumbled on that at first receiving an email for each file.

Comment: Deadooshka and Fred, thanks. The server path was edited for public post. Files uploaded correctly.

Comment: You're welcome Dan, glad it all worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a loop that displays the file names on the web page. You need a similar loop to store the file names in `$message_body`. You can incorporate this into the loop that you already have for moving the uploaded files. Perhaps something like this:

```
$message_body = "".$_POST["email"]." uploaded these files:\n";

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['tray']['name']); $i++) {

  $filename = $_FILES['tray']['name'][$i];
  $s_name = $_FILES['tray']['tmp_name'][$i];
  move_uploaded_file($s_name, 'https://example.com/inbox/'.$filename.'');

  $message_body .= "* " . $_FILES['tray']['name'][$i]
                .  "-> https://example.com/inbox/" . rawurlencode($filename)
                .  "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code appears to treat `$_FILES['tray']['name']` as an array.  Have you tried imploding it, with commas, to turn it from an array to a string:

```
 $message_body = "".$_POST["email"]." uploaded the file: ".implode(", ",$_FILES['tray']['name'])."https://example.com/inbox/".rawurlencode($filename)."
```

Comment: Thanks, Mainstreetmark. I'll give this a try next time.